# SQL Server Msg 50000 when using stored procedure to create folder

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ole

I'm using a stored procedure to create folders, which are then populated with files extracted from `varBinary` columns. The process works for many rows, but I'm getting the following error from others:

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.CreateFolder, Line 31 [Batch Start Line 0]

I'm not sure what this means, or why it would happen on some rows and not others.

My stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateFolder] 
    (@newfolder VARCHAR(1000)) 
AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @OLEfolder INT  
    DECLARE @OLEsource VARCHAR(255)  
    DECLARE @OLEdescription VARCHAR(255) 
    DECLARE @init INT  
    DECLARE @OLEfilesytemobject INT  

    -- it will fail if OLE automation not enabled
    EXEC @init=sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @OLEfilesytemobject OUT  

    IF @init <> 0  
    BEGIN  
        EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @OLEfilesytemobject  
        RETURN  
    END  

    -- check if folder exists  
    EXEC @init = sp_OAMethod @OLEfilesytemobject, 'FolderExists', @OLEfolder OUT, @newfolder  

    -- if folder doesn't exist, create it  
    IF @OLEfolder = 0  
    BEGIN  
        EXEC @init = sp_OAMethod @OLEfilesytemobject, 'CreateFolder', @OLEfolder OUT, @newfolder  
    END  

    -- in case of error, raise it   
    IF @init <> 0  
    BEGIN  
        EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @OLEfilesytemobject, @OLEsource OUT, @OLEdescription OUT  

        SELECT @OLEdescription = 'Could not create folder: ' + @OLEdescription  
        RAISERROR (@OLEdescription, 16, 1)   
    END  

    EXECUTE @init = sp_OADestroy @OLEfilesytemobject  
END
```

Then I'm using T-SQL to extract files using [this guide](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/sql/sqlserver/export-documents-saved-as-blob-binary-from-sql-server/)

```
USE MYDB
DECLARE @outPutPath varchar(50) = 'C:\MYDB\Export\Blob'
, @i bigint
, @init int
, @data varbinary(max) 
, @fPath varchar(max)  
, @folderPath  varchar(max) 

--Get Data into temp Table variable so that we can iterate over it 
DECLARE @Doctable TABLE 
                  (
                      id INT IDENTITY(1, 1), 
                      [Attachment_ID] VARCHAR(100),  
                      [File_Name] VARCHAR(100), 
                      [Call_Number] VARCHAR(100), 
                      [File_Object] VARBINARY(MAX) 
                  )

INSERT INTO @Doctable([Attachment_ID], [File_Name], [Call_Number], [File_Object])
    SELECT
        [Attachment_ID], [File_Name], [Call_Number], [File_Object] 
    FROM  
        [dbo].[Attachment] 
    WHERE 
        Call_Number = '32893'

    --SELECT * FROM @table

SELECT @i = COUNT(1) FROM @Doctable

WHILE @i >= 1
BEGIN 

    SELECT 
        @data = [File_Object],
        @fPath = @outPutPath + '\'+ [Call_Number] + '\' +[File_Name],
        @folderPath = @outPutPath + '\'+ [Call_Number]
    FROM 
        @Doctable 
    WHERE 
        id = @i

    --Create folder first
    EXEC [dbo].[CreateFolder]  @folderPath

    EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @init OUTPUT; -- An instance created
    EXEC sp_OASetProperty @init, 'Type', 1;  
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Open'; -- Calling a method
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Write', NULL, @data; -- Calling a method
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @fPath, 2; -- Calling a   method
    EXEC sp_OAMethod @init, 'Close'; -- Calling a method
    EXEC sp_OADestroy @init; -- Closed the resources

    PRINT 'Document Generated at - '+  @fPath   

    --Reset the variables for next use
    SELECT @data = NULL,
           @init = NULL,
           @fPath = NULL, 
           @folderPath = NULL

    SET @i -= 1
END
```

Anyone have ideas as to what's going wrong?

I tried using the edited versions of the stored procedure and T-SQL (by Marc), but the error displayed on every row and no files were generated. Reverting the T-SQL but keeping Marc's stored procedure gave the same result as the originals.

Comment: Did you check the folder names or file names you are trying to create for the rows that fail with the error message?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the folders and files are being created even when an error has shown. There aren't as many files created as there are rows in the table, but that seems to be due to other factors such as empty [File_Object]. Perhaps the errors were a red herring.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you tried to create a folder inside a nonexistent folder during extraction from database to file system.

Folders with this procedure can be created only inside an existing folder.

For example:

```
EXEC [dbo].[CreateFolder] 'C:\DocsFromDB\2019'
```

You cannot create folder `2019` if `DocsFromDB` does not exist. You should first create `DocsFromDB` to be able to create other folders inside.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using following code:

```
-- in case of error, raise it   
IF @init <> 0  
BEGIN  
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @OLEfilesytemobject, @OLEsource OUT, @OLEdescription OUT  

    SELECT @OLEdescription = 'Could not create folder: ' + @OLEdescription  
    RAISERROR (@OLEdescription, 16, 1)   
END
```

Use this:

```
-- in case of error, raise it   
IF @init <> 0  
BEGIN  
    EXEC @init = sp_OAGetErrorInfo @OLEfilesytemobject, @OLEsource OUT, @OLEdescription OUT
    IF @init = 0
        SELECT @OLEdescription = 'Could not create folder: ' + ISNULL(@OLEdescription,' Unknown') 
    ELSE
        SELECT @OLEdescription = 'Could not create folder: ' + 'Reason: Failed to determine'    
    RAISERROR (@OLEdescription, 16, 1)   
END
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I hit a similar issue you described with error 5000.

I was logging in via SQL Management Studio on a support box then connecting to remote SQL instance on server. I was trying to generate the files on my dev machine, not directly on the server.

When I logged directly onto the target SQL box, it worked perfectly.

Also had a subsequent failure with error 5000 when the folder F:\Documents I was outputting to had a share on it. I deleted the share, recreated the folder, and worked perfectly.... No idea why...

Might help someone.